# Reading shp with read_sf and converting to data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, r-sf

I'm reading several `.shp` files and I want to merge (bind rows) them into one sf data frame at the end. I tried several things but the result is not sf dataframe and the geometry cells are be in a list format.

Reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)  

# create sample sf data frames and export them to directory: /folder/
data1 <- data.frame(attr = c(1:10), lon = c(11:20), lat = c(21:30)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), dim = "XY") %>% st_set_crs(4326) 
data1 %>% write_sf("folder/data1.shp")
data2 <- data.frame(attr = c(11:20), lon = c(21:30), lat = c(31:40)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), dim = "XY") %>% st_set_crs(4326) 
data2 %>% write_sf("folder/data2.shp")

# function for reading the exported files
read_files <- function(filename){
 table <- read_sf(filename)
}

# getting the exported .shp files from the same directory
file_list <- list.files("folder/", pattern = ".shp", full.names = T)

# reading 
df <- map_df(file_list, read_files)
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

[image: Desired and current output]

Comment: Please include the packages that need to be loaded to make the example reproducible. Where does e.g. `map_df` come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is that purrr::map_df uses dplyr::bind_rows to bind the data.frames, which does not handle sfc columns or units class columns well.
Thus the warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  Vectorizing 'sfc_POINT' elements may not preserve their attributes
```

instead you can use base rbind like this (note you can just use st_read directly instead of read_files):

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(file_list, st_read))
```

see this discussion for more info:
https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2457